# Proof of Proposition 2.3.5 of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

When I read the Proposition 2.3.5 of Topping's *Lectures on the Ricci flow*. I can't understand why the spcial vector fields which satisfy (2.3.13)  do not loss generality.  In fact, in my view, they are really special. If denote
$$
\nabla X = (\nabla X)_i^j dx^i \otimes \partial_j
$$
then, there is
$$
(\nabla X)_i^j(p) =0   ~~~\forall i,j=1,...,n
$$
Besides, I think $X,Y,Z,W$ are independent of $t$, what is the mean of "at a 'time' $t$  " ?

> [image]

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly you are not familiar with [**Normal coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). It is a special coordinates that simplifies calculations if you need verify an identity **at a point** and has the following properties:

1. $\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)=0$ ($\Gamma_{ij}^k$ are Christoffel symbols)
2. $[\partial_i,\partial_j]$.

Note that (1) is correct just at $p$ not in neighborhood of $p$. so $\left(\nabla X\right)(p)=0$ in normal coordinates $(x^i)$.